# Java Palindrome checker

Tags: java, palindrome

I have a issue with my palindrome checker as it is not working properly. It must be able to test these 4 things:

```
    TestPalindrome("Madam, I'm Adam", true);
    TestPalindrome("addbda", false );
    TestPalindrome("", false);
    TestPalindrome("Dammit, I'm mad", true);
```

This is my code for the palindrome:

```
public static boolean IsPalindrome( String inputString )
{
    String reverse = "";
    for(int i = inputString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").length() -1; i>=0; i--){
        reverse = reverse + inputString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").charAt(i);
    }
    if(inputString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").equalsIgnoreCase(reverse.toString()) && !inputString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").isEmpty()){
        return true;
    }

    if(!inputString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").equalsIgnoreCase(reverse.toString()) && !inputString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").isEmpty()){
        return false;
    }

    if(inputString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").isEmpty()){
        return false;
    }

    else return true;
         }
}
```

This is what my output is:

```
TestPalindrome failed: expected true got false
TestPalindrome passed!
TestPalindrome passed!
TestPalindrome failed: expected true got false
```

Can anyone help me fix this so I get all passes in the list. I understand similar questions have been asked but I´m not asking how to do a palindrome checker but how to fix my specific one. I used those other questions to learn but for some reason my one doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain what your strategy is here

Comment: You need to debug your program to figure out the "some reason" which is preventing your program from passing the tests you run against it.  if you add `System.out.println("'" + inputString + "','" + reverse + "'");` after your `for()` loop finishes, what does it say?

Comment: Well I first try to reverse my inputString, I then put that if the inputString == the reverse of the inputString then it will return true. I also have it to ignore case and symbols and numbers. That is my strategy, Tyler.

Comment: Dan, this is what I get:

Comment: I'd follow @DanO's suggestion, but here's one other thing (it won't fix the problem but may help avoid other problems): Don't keep repeating `inputString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "")`.  Assign it to a variable and use that.

Comment: 'Madam, I'm Adam','madA mI madaM'

Comment: you also need to ignore white spaces

Comment: OK, I think you need to go one further.  Follow my suggestion and assign the result of `replaceAll` to a variable, then follow DanO's suggestion but put that variable in your `println` instead of `inputString`.  That will show you exactly which variables you're comparing with `equalsIgnoreCase`.  That should make it obvious what the problem is.

Comment: This is one of the lines it printed, it seems the inputString contains symbols but the reverse doesn't. Could this be the reason?

Comment: It would make it all a lot simpler (and more efficient) if you stopped doing the `replaceAll` call all the time: simply assign a new variable `String inputStringStripped = inputString.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");`, then use `inputStringStripped` instead of `inputString.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "")`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to such algorithm to work you need to consider to clean the punctual symbols like comma, semmicolon, aposthrofs etc (am talking about ';:' etc)

Java has a `StringBuilder` class and in there is a method to reverse strings

so if you clean the String to check, reverse it and compare it again itself you can see if it a palindrome or not...

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "Madam, I'm Adam";
    String word2 = "addbda";
    String word3 = "";
    String word4 = "Dammit, I'm mad";
    System.out.println(IsPalindrome(word));
    System.out.println(IsPalindrome(word2));
    System.out.println(IsPalindrome(word3));
    System.out.println(IsPalindrome(word4));
}

private static boolean IsPalindrome(String word) {
    String wordClean = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z  ]", "");
    String reversedWord =  new StringBuilder(wordClean).reverse().toString();
    System.out.println(wordClean);
    System.out.println(reversedWord);
        return reversedWord.equalsIgnoreCase(wordClean)&&!wordClean.isEmpty();
}
```

this will print

> MadamImAdam
> madAmImadaM
> true
>
> addbda
> adbdda
> false
>
> false (empty check)
>
> DammitImmad
> dammItimmaD
> true

Comment: Why not just replace everything that's not in `[A-Za-z]` with nothing, rather than just removing specific characters outside that range?

Comment: The third one should come out as false, not true. Everything else worked fine. The third one is when the inputString is null or "". What can I do to deal with that?

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa it's basically what OP does in the question using `[^A-Za-z ]` - it's just that includes space too.

Comment: @FredTheHomie thanks, I forgot to check if string is empty, now in there in the return statement... give a try and let me know...

Answer (score 0):

You are not removing spaces, so only strings with spaces in the same places are good. Just use `[^a-zA-Z]` against `[^a-zA-Z ]`

Comment: Thank it now works perfectly fine. I appreciate the help from you and everyone.